# GraphAPIError: Error validating access token: Session does not match current stored session. This may be because the user changed the password

Tags: facebook-graph-api, mobile

If I use the graph API with my app on a mobile phone to retrieve user events, I get the error:

```
GraphAPIError: Error validating access token: Session does not match current stored session. This may be because the user changed the password since the time the session was created or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons.
```

But if I try again a second time shortly after, it works. If I wait for too long (some hours), this problem re-appears.

My Python code is:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=TOKENS["user_token"])

time.sleep(0.6) # to deal with Graph API latency, although problem is visibly not here

event = graph.get_object(id=event_id, fields='attending_count,declined_count,interested_count,is_viewer_admin,is_page_owned, owner,name')
```

Everything works with a Desktop computer.